# Change default health and prometheus actuator endpoints in spring webflux

Tags: java, rest, redirect, spring-webflux

I am building a new webflux spring service and I have enabled actuator (health, info and prometheus). The infrastructure where this service will be deployed is kind of old-ish and the monitoring tools are already configured to look for "/health", "/metrics" and it seems like it's difficult for the admins (!?) to look for different urls.

Now, I could try to make a dummy controller and respond with some 300 status and redirect to the actual endpoint - but the monitoring tool is configured not to follow redirects.

The best option would be (IMO) to **configure** spring in `application.yml` to use a separate url (like, instead of `/actuator/health` to simply use `/health`) but I failed to find any relevant resource.

The next best option would be to implement a new RestController and then forward the requests - something like this:

```
@RestController
public class ObservabilityForwardConfig {

    @GetMapping("/metrics")
    public Mono<Rendering> forwardToMetrics() {
        log.info("metrics endpoint was hit");
        return Mono.just(Rendering.redirectTo("/actuator/prometheus").build());
    }
}
```

This one fails with some weird exception:

```
2022-10-05 14:07:27,211 [reactor-http-epoll-4] ERROR e.e.e.c.s.s.c.RestExceptionHandler - Got an unhandled exception: 
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.DefaultRendering]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.DefaultRendering and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.encodeValue(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:230)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler eu.europa.ec.cc.storage.service.config.ObservabilityForwardConfig#forwardToMetrics() [DispatcherHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.encodeValue(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:230)
...
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.DefaultRendering and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1300)
```

and this is the reason why I am looking for some config alternative.

Comment: `The best option would be (IMO) to configure spring in application.yml to use a separate url (like, instead of /actuator/health to simply use /health) but I failed to find any relevant resource.` why not just read the spring boot documentation and read the chapter on actuators? wasnt that hard to find https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.monitoring.customizing-management-server-context-path

Comment: YOU.ARE.RIGHT. Thanks. I missed that part. Thanks. Would you please post your answer here so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring Actuator library has full support for changing the names and paths of it's endpoints. Its pointed out in the [actuator chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.monitoring.customizing-management-server-context-path) in the spring boot documentation.

The following example remaps `/actuator/health` to `/healthcheck`:

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=healthcheck
```

so the syntax is:

```
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.<what_endpoint>=<new_endpoint_path>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found how to configure spring how to overwrite the paths for those actuators but I found why my forwarder class was not working. I should have annotated it with `@Controller` instead of `@RestController`:

```
@Controller
public class ObservabilityForwardConfig {

    @GetMapping("/metrics")
    public Mono<Rendering> forwardToMetrics() {
        return Mono.just(Rendering.redirectTo("/actuator/prometheus").build());
    }
}
```